# Cannot load packages automatically in R -- what is the correct way to set up the .Rprofile script?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to change the settings of R running on my Mac so that it automatically loads packages I want. I created a .Rprofile file and dropped it into "~/", my home directory.

In the .Rprofile file, all I wrote was:

```
library("package1")
library("package2")
library("package3")
```

However, when I save and exit R, then go back, the packages have not installed by themselves. Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How did you save it? Did you make sure a different file extension wasn't appended to the end?

Comment: Thats it, wow, thank you! it was saved as .R instead of .Rprofile. thanks again!

Comment: Be careful with your phrasing. There is a difference between installing a package and loading a package.

Comment: Keep in mind there's also a `.Rprofile` in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/versions/....`